# What machine learning algorithm to use and how to implement it?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a virtual world with a grid filled with squares (x by y). There are entities that can do:
1. move 1 step in the four cardinal directions
2. eat food
3. fight another entity of a different type
4. mate with the same type of entity to reproduce (create one more of that type of entity)

The objective is to obtain the highest score possible.
The score is calculated by:
+1 per food eaten
+1 per enemy killed
+1 per entity of that type

The inputs (neurons) are as follows:
1. position (x, y) on board
2. board size
3. types of entities in adjacent squares (including food, and null if empty)

I would like to create a program that will create hidden neurons that give rise to a sophisticated moving and attacking pattern that will allow it to obtain the highest score.

Which algorithm should I use?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Note that programming is offtopic here.

Comment: I think it is a good but subjective question: no one really knows which idea will work best before you go ahead and implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you try to apply [reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning), maybe deep [Q-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) or some other form of RL.

I don't know if those are going to be the best set of features (the best way to represent the input).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! How would you allow the program to create intermediate neurons?

Comment: @RandomPieKevin, I don't understand your question.  You get to choose the neural network structure; you can make it whatever you want to be, and have as many or as few neurons as you want.  You don't need a program to do that for you -- you can choose the neural network architecture yourself.

Comment: I thought that true AI would create their intermediate neurons themselves; thus, the true learning.

Comment: @RandomPieKevin, I don't know what you mean by "true AI" or "true learning", or where you got that idea from, but no, there's no reason why you need to be restricted to that, and that's not how machine learning is normally done.  My answer certainly counts as learning and counts as AI; there's nothing fake or untrue about it.  In any case, that restriction is not in the question, so if you have some additional requirements, I suggest you edit the question to clarify what your requirements are and what approaches you've already considered and rejected and why.